# I get this error when I try to render some templates in my django project, what's wrong?

Tags: python, django, templates

I get this error when I try to render or display to a localhost the templates in my django project, and below is my error:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /
Could not parse the remainder: '/style_home.css' from 'css/style_home.css'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.1.3
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Could not parse the remainder: '/style_home.css' from 'css/style_home.css'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 703, in __init__
Raised during:  myapp.views.home
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0
Python Path:    
['D:\\IT\\Proiecte Python\\Django Site\\mysite',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

I expected to view my html files render in the localhost site, and that's what I did
Here is my code in urls file:

```
from django import views
from django.contrib import admin
from myapp import views
from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('about_me/', views.about_me, name='about_me')
]
```

and also I have in each html document on the first paragraph this django html line graph:

```
{% load static %}
```

because I had and some static files, and I created a static folder also with css and js:
And in the settings I have also implemented this code:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'], #that's in the TEMPLATES in settings
```

and for static folder this lines of code:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = BASE_DIR, 'static'
```

Comment: As it is a `TemplateSyntaxError` where is your template?

Comment: Please format your code block(s), logs and errors, in order to make your question more readable, and receive better quality answers. For more information, take a look on this link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks